About the isometric extension of the erasure channel
I'm doing exercises 5.2.6 and 5.2.7 in Quantum Information Theory by Wilde. In 5.2.6, it asks us to show that an isometric extension of the erasure channel is
\begin{align}
U &\overset{a}{=} \sqrt{1-\epsilon}(|0\rangle_B\langle0|_A+|1\rangle_B\langle1|_A \otimes|e\rangle_E)+\sqrt{\epsilon}|e\rangle_B\langle0|_A\otimes |0\rangle_E + \sqrt{\epsilon}|e\rangle_B\langle1|_A\otimes |1\rangle_E\\
&\overset{b}{=}\sqrt{1-\epsilon}I_{A\to B} \otimes |e\rangle_E + \sqrt{\epsilon}I_{A\to E} \otimes |e\rangle_B.
\end{align}
The Kraus representations of the erasure channel are given before, and by the connection between the isometric extension and Kraus representation, we have the equality $a$. Then I have the following question:
To show the equality $b$ holds, I found that
\begin{align}
|0\rangle_B\langle0|_A+|1\rangle_B\langle1|_A = I_{A\to B},\\
\langle0|_A\otimes |0\rangle_E +\langle1|_A\otimes |1\rangle_E = I_{A\to E}.
\end{align}
But this gives $\sqrt{1-\epsilon}I_{A\to B} \otimes |e\rangle_E + \sqrt{\epsilon}|e\rangle_B I_{A\to E} $, while obviously $|e\rangle_B I_{A\to E} \neq  I_{A\to E} \otimes |e\rangle_B$. Why is that?

The operator
$$
(|i\rangle_B\langle j|_A) \otimes |k\rangle_E
$$
represents a linear map from $A \to BE$. We could also write this as
$$
(|i\rangle_B \otimes I_E)(\langle j|_A \otimes |k\rangle_E)
$$
i.e. as first a map $A \to E$ followed by a map $E \to BE$. If you use this second representation you will find that
$$
\sqrt{\epsilon} |e\rangle_B \langle 0 |_A \otimes |0\rangle_E + \sqrt{\epsilon} |e\rangle_B \langle 1 |_A \otimes |1\rangle_E = \sqrt{\epsilon}|e\rangle_B \otimes I_{A \to E}
$$
as desired.
